# Laravel Storage::get() is not working return empty value

Tags: laravel

I want to get image file in laravel storage folder  and encode it to base64. If I use this code it always return empty value

```
$data = base64_encode(Storage::disk('public')->get('/customer/Avatars',"image.png"));
```

In localhost this code works

```
$data = base64_encode(file_get_contents(public_path().'/storage/customer/Avatars/'."image.png"));
```

but after upload to cpanel this above code give me this error

```
ErrorException: file_get_contents(/home/site/wwwroot/public/storage/customer/Avatars/image.png): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in file /home/site/wwwroot/app/Http/Controllers/Customer/CustomerProfileController.php on line 56
```

How can I get this file?

Comment: it says the file doesn't exist ... nothing we can do for you about that

Comment: use your Cpanel to check if the file exists or not.  And check your path directory, be careful about Case Sensitive

Comment: Show your Laravel base directory structure so that we can understand if the "public" folder has the correct folders and files.

Answer (score 0):

you can any found file path on storage folder with laravel global [storage_path](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/helpers#method-storage-path) helper

```php
$imagePath=storage_path('customer/Avatars/image.png');
```

if you get file path in public folder

```php
$imagePath=public_path('customer/Avatars/image.png');
```

Answer (score -1):

This happened to me and I would like to share it because some of you can be having the same problem, I was trying to use Storage::get() method for encoding a file, but, that returned an empty field, finally I realized that the file that I was getting with the method was empty inside, so make sure your dummy files has some content inside, otherwise it will always return empty.